# compiling a win32 c++ console application in visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to build example application from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/opening-a-file-for-reading-or-writing). In Visual Studio I created a Win32 C++ console application. when I try to compile I get a lot of errors about undeclared identifiers. The code as mentioned in the link is:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include "stdafx.h"

void DisplayError(LPTSTR lpszFunction)
// Routine Description:
// Retrieve and output the system error message for the last-error code
{
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError();

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf,
        0,
        NULL);

    lpDisplayBuf =
        (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT,
        (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf)
            + lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction)
            + 40) // account for format string
            * sizeof(TCHAR));

    if (FAILED(StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf,
        LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),
        TEXT("%s failed with error code %d as follows:\n%s"),
        lpszFunction,
        dw,
        lpMsgBuf)))
    {
        printf("FATAL ERROR: Unable to output error code.\n");
    }

    _tprintf(TEXT("ERROR: %s\n"), (LPCTSTR)lpDisplayBuf);

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
}

int  main(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{
    HANDLE hFile;
    char DataBuffer[] = "This is some test data to write to the file.";
    DWORD dwBytesToWrite = (DWORD)strlen(DataBuffer);
    DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
    BOOL bErrorFlag = FALSE;

    printf("\n");
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage Error:\tIncorrect number of arguments\n\n");
        _tprintf(TEXT("%s <file_name>\n"), argv[0]);
        return;
    }

    hFile = CreateFile(argv[1],                // name of the write
        GENERIC_WRITE,          // open for writing
        0,                      // do not share
        NULL,                   // default security
        CREATE_NEW,             // create new file only
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,  // normal file
        NULL);                  // no attr. template

    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        DisplayError(TEXT("CreateFile"));
        _tprintf(TEXT("Terminal failure: Unable to open file \"%s\" for write.\n"), argv[1]);
        return;
    }

    _tprintf(TEXT("Writing %d bytes to %s.\n"), dwBytesToWrite, argv[1]);

    bErrorFlag = WriteFile(
        hFile,           // open file handle
        DataBuffer,      // start of data to write
        dwBytesToWrite,  // number of bytes to write
        &dwBytesWritten, // number of bytes that were written
        NULL);            // no overlapped structure

    if (FALSE == bErrorFlag)
    {
        DisplayError(TEXT("WriteFile"));
        printf("Terminal failure: Unable to write to file.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        if (dwBytesWritten != dwBytesToWrite)
        {
            // This is an error because a synchronous write that results in
            // success (WriteFile returns TRUE) should write all data as
            // requested. This would not necessarily be the case for
            // asynchronous writes.
            printf("Error: dwBytesWritten != dwBytesToWrite\n");
        }
        else
        {
            _tprintf(TEXT("Wrote %d bytes to %s successfully.\n"), dwBytesWritten, argv[1]);
        }
    }

    CloseHandle(hFile);
}
```

but when I try to build it I get:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: trainer, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Build started 5/7/2021 1:46:02 AM.
1>     1>
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>         Touching "x64\Debug\trainer.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
1>       ClCompile:
1>         All outputs are up-to-date.
1>         trainer.cpp
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(7): error C2065: 'LPTSTR': undeclared identifier
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(7): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'lpszFunction'
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(10): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(10): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(51): error C2065: 'HANDLE': undeclared identifier
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(51): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'hFile'
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(51): error C2065: 'hFile': undeclared identifier
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(53): error C2065: 'DWORD': undeclared identifier
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(53): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'dwBytesToWrite'
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(53): error C2065: 'dwBytesToWrite': undeclared identifier
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(53): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'strlen'
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(53): error C3861: 'strlen': identifier not found
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(54): error C2065: 'DWORD': undeclared identifier
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(54): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'dwBytesWritten'
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(54): error C2065: 'dwBytesWritten': undeclared identifier
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(55): error C2065: 'BOOL': undeclared identifier
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(55): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'bErrorFlag'
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(55): error C2065: 'bErrorFlag': undeclared identifier
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(55): error C2065: 'FALSE': undeclared identifier
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(61): error C3861: 'TEXT': identifier not found
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(62): error C2561: 'main': function must return a value
1>         d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(49): note: see declaration of 'main'
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(65): error C2065: 'hFile': undeclared identifier
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(66): error C2065: 'GENERIC_WRITE': undeclared identifier
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(69): error C2065: 'CREATE_NEW': undeclared identifier
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(70): error C2065: 'FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL': undeclared identifier
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(65): error C3861: 'CreateFile': identifier not found
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(73): error C2065: 'hFile': undeclared identifier
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(73): error C2065: 'INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE': undeclared identifier
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(75): error C3861: 'TEXT': identifier not found
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(75): error C3861: 'DisplayError': identifier not found
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(76): error C3861: 'TEXT': identifier not found
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(77): error C2561: 'main': function must return a value
1>         d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(49): note: see declaration of 'main'
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(80): error C3861: 'TEXT': identifier not found
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(80): error C2065: 'dwBytesToWrite': undeclared identifier
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(82): error C2065: 'bErrorFlag': undeclared identifier
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(83): error C2065: 'hFile': undeclared identifier
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(85): error C2065: 'dwBytesToWrite': undeclared identifier
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(86): error C2065: 'dwBytesWritten': undeclared identifier
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(82): error C3861: 'WriteFile': identifier not found
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(89): error C2065: 'FALSE': undeclared identifier
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(89): error C2065: 'bErrorFlag': undeclared identifier
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(91): error C3861: 'TEXT': identifier not found
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(91): error C3861: 'DisplayError': identifier not found
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(96): error C2065: 'dwBytesWritten': undeclared identifier
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(96): error C2065: 'dwBytesToWrite': undeclared identifier
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(106): error C3861: 'TEXT': identifier not found
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(106): error C2065: 'dwBytesWritten': undeclared identifier
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(110): error C2065: 'hFile': undeclared identifier
1>     1>
1>d:\moki\projects\trainer\trainer\trainer.cpp(110): error C3861: 'CloseHandle': identifier not found
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.20
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I am new to Visual Studio and Windows API. Is there something I need to do in the configuration / settings that I am unaware?

Comment: `#include "stdafx.h"` needs to be the first header included in your source.

Comment: If you don't need pre-compiled headers then you could turn them off and remove `#include "stdafx.h"` but if you do have pre-compiled headers then you would expect `#include <windows.h>` to be inside the pre-compiled header.